# A kohen who marries Gerusha as Mashgiach

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, kohen-priest, edim-witnesses

Is a Kohen who marries a Gerusha(divorcee) but is observant in Shabbos and Kashrus allowed to be a Mashgiach of a food processor/restaurant?

Comment: How do you know he's observant in Shabbos and Kashrus?

Comment: What do you mean by "Mashgiach"? If he marries a Gerusha, he obviously does not see himslef as obligated to the Halacha, and the observance he may keep, may be just a habbit or peer pressure.

Answer (score 4):

The Rambam defines the parameters of a *Rasha* Hilchos Eidus 10,2 as someone who transgresses a negative Mitzva, and that person cannot testify:

> אי זהו רשע כל שעבר עבירה שחייבין עליה מלקות זהו רשע ופסול שהרי התורה קראה למחוייב מלקות רשע

So a Kohein who married a Divorcee cannot testify because he transgresses Vayikra 21,7:

> "ואשה גרושה מאישה לא יקחו"

This applies to Testifying for Kashrus, Tuma or anything requiring one witness called *Eid echad beissurin*, as well as being one of 2 eidim for regular Eidus e.g *Davar Sheamamon*. This is indicated in Kesef Mishna Eidus 11,2 who says an Am haaretz who is suspect to transgressing Mitzvos because he hasn't learnt Torah and doesn't act with *derech eretz* is Passul for Eidus, so someone who transgresses on purpose is definitely prohibited to testify :

> בפסחים ס"פ אלו עוברין (דף מ"ט:) ת"ר וכו' אין מוסרין עדות לע"ה ואין מקבלין ממנו עדות ובחגיגה פרק חומר בקדש אמאי דתניא א"ר יוסי מפני מה הכל נאמנים על טהרת יין ושמן כל ימות השנה כדי שלא יהא כל אחד ואחד הולך ובונה במה לעצמו וכו' אמר רב פפא כמאן מקבלין האידנא סהדותא מע"א כרבי יוסי וסובר רבינו דבחגיגה מיירי בע"ה שיש לו דרך ארץ ומצות אבל אינו לא במקרא ולא במשנה ובפסחים מיירי בסתם ע"ה דסתמו הוא דליתיה לא במקרא ולא במשנה ולא בדרך ארץ:.

See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 128,40: that we can reinstate a Kohen as a Kosher person if he Divorces his wife or Makes a *Neder al daas Rabim* that any benefit from his wife is forbidden  for him. This would directly lead to divorce his wife at the soonest opportunity.

Comment: Hi, I think that if someone keeps a certain mitzvah(like kashrut), then he's an acceptable witness for that particular mitzvah, even though he may not be reliable for other mitzvot. Being pasul for edut applies only to testifying for beit din matters. In cases where only one witness is required(like kashrut, a woman for matters of her niddah, and some cases of agunot), a witness that wouldn't otherwise be accepted in a beit din, would be accepted(like kashrut).

Comment: @chachamNisan i'm not compelled to listen to your opinion if it contradcts Halacha unless you bring a concrete proof.

Comment: Feel free to check it out...